# Oracle SQL - REGEXP_LIKE not working as expected in CHECK constraint

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, check-constraints

I'm using **Oracle SQL** and I want to add a CHECK constraint that checks a regular expression when I create a table. However, the REGEXP_LIKE function behaves differently from online RegEx testing tools.

Suppose I want to create a table called `Testing` with only one attribute called `roomNo`. I want `roomNo` to only store 4 numerical digits optionally followed by an uppercase letter (eg. `1234`, `1234A`):

```
CREATE TABLE Testing (
    roomNo      char(5),
    CONSTRAINT check_roomNo CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(roomNo, '^\d{4}[A-Z]?$'))
);
insert into Testing values ('1234X');
insert into Testing values ('1234');  -- Unexpected error here
```

When I run this script, I can successfully insert `1234X` into the table but Oracle SQL throws me an error when inserting `1234`:

```
Error starting at line : 5 in command -
insert into Testing values ('1234')
Error report -
ORA-02290: check constraint (USER.CHECK_ROOMNO) violated
```

I don't quite understand why this is an error since when I test the RegEx `^\d{4}[A-Z]?$` in an online RegEx testing tool, it can match both `1234X` and `1234`. [Here is a link](https://regex101.com/r/pSj6D5/1) to a RegEx testing tool that uses the RegEx I used in the REGEXP_LIKE function. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, I found that `roomNo` having the data type of `char(5)` is the culprit of this problem.

According to Oracle documentation on `char` [in here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a77069/b_char.htm):

> When you insert a character value into a CHAR database column, Oracle does not strip trailing blanks. If the value is shorter than the defined width of the column, Oracle blank-pads the value to the defined width

When I insert `1234` into the table, since `1234` has a shorter length than the defined width of the column (ie. width of 5), Oracle adds blank pads to the right of the string so that the string is stored as `1234`  with a single blank space after `1234`.

Therefore, the string `1234`  fails to match the RegEx `^\d{4}[A-Z]?$` since the last character of the string (ie. a blank space) does not match `[A-Z]`.

A solution I can come up with is to use the RegEx of `^\d{4}[A-Z ]?$` so that it can match the single blank space located at the 5th character.

**Edit:**

Another solution is to use `RTRIM()` function to remove tailing whitespaces at the right:

```
CONSTRAINT check_roomNo CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(RTRIM(roomNo), '^\d{4}[A-Z]?$'))
```

Comment: There is; as values aren't fixed to 5 characters in length, switch to **VARCHAR2** datatype.

Comment: That was my first thought too. `char` is just trouble - my advice is to avoid it unless you actually need trailing blanks appended to shorter values. Why anybody would ever want trailing blanks appended, I can't imagine.